# Is there a a reputation system for me among villagers?

Tags: a-dark-room

I was wondering if there was a reputation system that makes my villagers love/hate me with things such as choosing whether or not to hang the thief, cure plagues, give to beggars, etc. impacting it.

Will being nice give me a different outcome than not doing anything? I'm trying to get the best ending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, there is not a reputation system for the player character.**

Since *A Dark Room* is open-source, I was able to verify the following:

- No instances of the word "[reputation](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/search?q=reputation)", "[rep](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/search?q=rep)", or "[karma](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/search?q=karma)" exist in the game's code base.

Spoilers about event outcomes:

> - For the [thief event](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/blob/48ece588ed65e3c1c412ee57143ef447185cd0c9/script/events/global.js), hanging the thief results in some of your stolen resources being returned. Letting the thief go results in learning a stealth perk. Either way, after the event, you stop getting your resources stolen.
>
> - For the [beggar event](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/blob/48ece588ed65e3c1c412ee57143ef447185cd0c9/script/events/room.js#L192), your reward is a chance to receive some scales, teeth, or cloth.
>
> - For the [plague event](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/blob/48ece588ed65e3c1c412ee57143ef447185cd0c9/script/events/outside.js#L155), your choice changes how many villagers die.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that they could call their system something else other than "reputation" or "karma", but seeing that the actual event(s) code doesn't seem to increment/decrement some sort of "reputation", its safe to say no system exists.